# General Method to find area of super triangle

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry

Is there a general way to find a area of a super triangle?

I know the definition of a super triangle is the following: In the disk model of hyperbolic plane, the area bounded by three points M, P, and Q is called a super triangle if at least one of these three points belongs to the boundary of the disk.

I also know that we can have multiple scenarios here:

1. M is on the boundary
2. M, P are on the boundary
3. M, P, Q are on the boundary.

Is there a general way to find the area for such a triangle when given all three points? For example, $M = 1$, $P = i$, $Q = 1 + \sqrt{2}$

Comment: "the disk model" is ambiguous; do you mean Poincaré? Beltrami-Klein? something else? (Typically, such a model has radius $1$, so $Q=1+\sqrt{2}$ wouldn't be a point in it.) ... Area is equal to the angular defect of the triangle; that is, $\pi-(\text{angle sum})$. The angle at a point on the disk boundary has measure $0$, so case $(3)$ is easy. Calculating angles at arbitrary points can be a bit complicated. ... Please provide some context about your level of familiarity with the tools and techniques involved here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The area of a hyperbolic triangle (assuming hyperbolic space with curvature $-1$) is equal to $\pi$ minus the sum of its interior angles. If one or more vertices of the triangle are on the boundary of hyperbolic space (usually referred to as *ideal points*), the interior angle at these vertices is 0. The formula still holds in this case.

Assuming the three points you provide are in the Poincaré *half-plane* model, the interior angle at $P$ is $\pi/4$ while the angles at $M$ and $Q$ are $0$, so the area of this triangle is $3\pi/4$.